# Python input, unwanted recurring prompt

Tags: python, input

I am writing code in python for an online course. The code should accept input integers from 0-10, and prompt the user to enter other values if these are not written into the input prompt.

Here is my code:

```py
def user_choice(): 
    
    #Initial
    choice = 'WRONG'
    acceptable_range = range(0,11)
    within_range = False 
    
    #Two conditions to check 
    #Digit and within_range 
    while choice.isdigit() == False or within_range == False: 
    
        choice = input("Please enter a number 0-10: ")
        
        #Digit check 
        if choice.isdigit() == False: 
            print('Sorry that is not a digit.')
        
        #Range check 
        if choice.isdigit() == True:
            if int(choice) in acceptable_range: 
                within_range == True 
                
            else:
                print('Sorry, out of acceptable range.')
                within_range == False
    
    return int(choice)
```

After running this, I can see the input prompt. If I input a letter or number besides 1-10, I get the appropriate message.
If I enter a number 1-10, the function runs and displays that number, but does not end the input  with an Out [] output like it should. It asks for another input. Why do I still get the input prompt?

Comment: There is no reason to see `Out []` from your program. It seems like it is working as intended.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you have a typo for the `==` should be `=`

```
def user_choice(): 
    
    #Initial
    choice = 'WRONG'
    acceptable_range = range(0,11)
    within_range = False 
    
    #Two conditions to check 
    #Digit and within_range 
    while choice.isdigit() == False or within_range == False: 
    
        choice = input("Please enter a number 0-10: ")
        
        #Digit check 
        if choice.isdigit() == False: 
            print('Sorry that is not a digit.')
        
        #Range check 
        if choice.isdigit() == True:
            if int(choice) in acceptable_range: 
                within_range = True 
                
            else:
                print('Sorry, out of acceptable range.')
                within_range = False
    
    return int(choice)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, `var = 5` is a variable affectation and `var == 5` is an equality check.

replace `within_range == False` by `within_range = False`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign `within_range` with `==` instead of `=`.

It should be

```
within_range = True
```

Using `==` is for comparing values, `=` is to assign values to a variable.

Comment: Great, this solved the problem, and the output is correct now! Cheers, thanks a bunch.